# Accessing Sublist throws ConcurrentModificationException after XML de-serialization

Tags: java, xstream, sublist

I am using XStrem-1.4.4 for XML serialization and de-serialization.  I am trying to create a sublist of a ArrayList object as shown in the code snippet below :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();

    someList.add("String1");
    someList.add("String2");
    someList.add("String3");

    List<String> someSubList = someList.subList(0, 2);

    for (String string : someSubList)
    {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    System.out.println("=====================================");

    XStream xstr = new XStream();
    String subListXML = xstr.toXML(someSubList);

    System.out.println(subListXML);
    System.out.println("=====================================");

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> subList = (List<String>) xstr.fromXML(subListXML);

    for (String string : subList)
    {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

}
```

When I run this code with JAVA 7 I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1169)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.listIterator(ArrayList.java:1049)
    at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:299)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.iterator(ArrayList.java:1045)
    at com.test.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:36)
```

But it works fine with JAVA 6.

What I have found is while working with JAVA 7 following XML structure is created :

```
<java.util.ArrayList_-SubList>
  <parent class="list">
    <string>String1</string>
    <string>String2</string>
    <string>String3</string>
  </parent>
  <parentOffset>0</parentOffset>
  <offset>0</offset>
  <size>2</size>
  <outer-class reference="../parent"/>
</java.util.ArrayList_-SubList>
```

whereas while working with JAVA 6 the structure created is :

```
<java.util.RandomAccessSubList>
    <l class="list">
      <string>String1</string>
      <string>String2</string>
      <string>String3</string>
    </l>
    <offset>0</offset>
    <size>2</size>
    <expectedModCount>3</expectedModCount>
</java.util.RandomAccessSubList>
```

As [specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int)) says

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

I tried resolving this problem by replacing line

```
List<String> someSubList = someList.subList(0, 2);
```

with

```
List<String> someSubList = new ArrayList<String>(someList.subList(0, 2));
```

It works completely fine with both JAVA 6 and JAVA 7 framing following XML structure :

```
<list>
   <string>String1</string>
   <string>String2</string>
</list>
```

What I want to know is why it did not considered sublist creation as structural modification in case of JAVA 6?

And why the error occurred after XML de-serialization and not before that in case of JAVA 7?

Comment: You are not guaranteed to get a ConcurrentModificationException if you concurrently modify a list. Perhaps the implementation changed in the new version do in this case it could detect the concurrent modification.

Comment: then why it did not detect the modification before serialization?